# Smelly and Pingable people

Tags: discussion, chat

We have a bot that helps you ping people in the [classroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174/the-classroom).

The command `!!/help` will provide the following:

```
!!/people `<all/unpingable/pingable>`   
all - Lists everyone who is in the ping index   
unpingable - Lists everyone who is in the ping index and is not pingable   
pingable - Lists everyone who is pingable   
!!/ping `<username/@username>` `<msg>` - Pings `<username>` with `<msg>`   
!!/help - Prints this help page   
!!/alive - Says "I'm alive" if the bot is alive
```

These are largely to help you determine who can be pinged from the classroom at the given moment.

Comment: All hail and thank @thesecretmaster for creating Smelly.

Comment: If I understand correctly, someone who is "pingable" is someone I can ping directly with the `@user` syntax. Someone who is "unpingable" cannot be pinged that way, but _can_ be pinged with the `!!/ping <user> <msg>` syntax using Smelly. Correct?